# An array with elements containing sub-elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, tree

I am fairly new to the C++ language, and I am curious if there is an item that would work for me. `Array`s store multiple elements. As I believe it, `dictionary`s (or `map`s) store items and an ID for them. There's also collections. However, I am interested in more of a tree format for an array. I have lots of items that I need to store in an array, but each of those items also needs to easily reference sub-elements, like so:

```
    Jason
      /\
   Age  Weight
    |      |
   14     140
```

I'm curious if there is an item that would suit my needs for this. As you should be able to see in the above model, I have an item (Jason), with multiple sub-models (like a tree).

My program randomly creates people with these attributes (age, weight, and name), and so I can't have a specific array for each person as I don't know how many there will be. Is there a way to hold these trees for easy access?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, some_numeric_type>>` sounds about right. The outer map is a pairing of people's names with a map of that person's attributes.

Comment: Or `struct person { std::string name; int age; int weight;}; std::vector<person> people;` (cache efficiency for the win)

Comment: Agreed. If the attributes are the same for everybody, the `struct` wins hands down.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you! I had only heard of `struct`s before and I did not know their use. This will work perfectly for my needs.

Comment: [List of C++ standard containers with documentation links.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Answer (score 3):

You could just create a person struct.

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    int weight;
};

std::vector< Person > persons;
persons.emplace_back( Person() ); // with your variables;
```

When you don't want to have the EXACTLY same person in your array,
use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (an associative container) instead.

Comment: Also a `std::set` is not a hash list.  It is an RB-Tree.  `std::unordered_set` is a hashed container.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for pointing that out. I actually thought this was the same.